# Functional languages: Real-life Examples

Tags: functional-programming

Do functional languages bring anything in the resolution of everyday business problems?

Are there any successful projects that have been implemented using a functional language (ideally with a published test case)?

Comment: Yes... take a look at the talks at CUFP (Commercial Users of Functional Programming) at http://cufp.galois.com/

Comment: @nlucaroni: Your comment sure looks like an answer -- please post it as an answer so I can upvote it.

Comment: @S.Lott - You can upvote comments, for what it's worth.

Comment: @nlucaroni: I was at first delighted by the wording of your answer, but the site is (how funny) not ... functional ! The main page embeds into itself when you click the "visit CUFP web site" link. 8-/

Comment: @Patrick: Oh, but recursion is very functional indeed. Enjoy. And if you are giving up that easily, then you've found your answer.

Comment: While I applaud the attempts by people to edit this into something useful, it now just sounds like a vague poll question.

Comment: @gnovice: It looks like Austin and I were editing at the same time and I won the race condition.  I've rolled back to the previous version, since I think it sound better.  Feel free to add (or subtract) more if it still sounds too vague.

Comment: guys, that's a VERY important question!  Using the examples posted as answers, we can persuade our bosses to allow us to use functional languages in our projects as well!  Please, don't close and +1 to Patrick.

Comment: Thanks, Pavel. And while (or because ?) my initial wording was a bit sceptic and controversial, I got plenty of good information.

Comment: Here are the videos from CUFP: http://vimeo.com/album/128851

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are quite a few listed on [Functional Programming in the Real World](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/realworld/index.html).  From the site:

> The main criterion for being real-world is that the program was written primarily to perform some task, not primarily to experiment with functional programming.

Comment: You got it, even if you made the question (which is no more a question) and the answer. Thanks to the other ones as well. Looks like I have some reading to do and opinions to revise.

Answer (score 10):

The [Xen hypervisor](http://citrix.com/English/ps2/products/product.asp?contentID=683148) is at base, implemented in OCAML; and Erlang is deployed in ultra-high reliability telephony systems (the ones that have zero down-time over periods of years).

Answer (score 3):

One implementation of Perl 6, [Pugs](http://www.pugscode.org/), is written in Haskell, but it has largely given way to the standard Rakudo Perl implementation.

Comment: Creating a language interpreter is hardly an "everyday business problem"; you yourself say Pugs isn't really a success but has been superseded by a conventional implementation.

Comment: They did fairly successfully implement Perl. They didn't stop the project because they failed to implement the language, they stopped because they didn't need two implementations, and the Parrot version was preferred.

Comment: What was the performance of Pugs like compared to the mainstream Perl implementation?

Answer (score 3):

Friends of mine use Haskell every day to implement financial algorithms.

Comment: Could you add a link to his employer?

Answer (score 3):

There was a talk at the Lang.NET conference about how they'd used F# to improve the performance of an insurance application, which is about as everyday as you can get.  [Silverlight video](http://www.langnetsymposium.com/2009/talks/21-AmanderLauter-FSharpConcurrency.html), [WMV video](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/6/A/76A69AE5-72B5-4005-BBD9-7EA5F4795014/21-AmanderLauter-FSharpConcurrency.wmv).  That said, most of the focus of that talk is on F#'s concurrency support, less on the idiomatically functional aspects of the language.

Comment: Video is ok, thanks. I was impressed by the comprarison in execution timings. I was less conviced by the 8 weeks training for a team to maintain this, but I guess it may be valuable in some situations. +1

Comment: *laughter*  Yes, she seemed far more blase about the cross-training costs than I would have been... but then I guess she was also being paid for giving the training...!

Comment: "I was less conviced by the 8 weeks training for a team to maintain this". Why?

Answer (score 3):

[Xmonad](http://xmonad.org/) is a dynamically tiling X11 window manager that is written and configured in Haskell.

Facebook's chat feature makes heavy use of Erlang. http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=14218138919&id=9445547199&index=0

Answer (score 2):

Have you heard of [Lisp machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_machine) before?  The [emacs editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs_Lisp) also makes extensive use of Lisp.

Comment: you may allready know this but Lisp isn't especially Functional.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_%28programming_language%29  You can program it using functional techniques, but the same can be said for most languages.  

Lisp is considered to be a multi paradigm language

Comment: True, Lisp supports other paradigms, but I'd consider it primarily a functional language.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that the Lotus Notes formula language is an example of a widely used real world functional programming language.