# Do functional languages cope well with complexity?

Tags: functional-programming, complexity-theory

I am curious how functional languages compare (in general) to more "traditional" languages such as C# and Java for large programs.  Does program flow become difficult to follow more quickly than if a non-functional language is used?  Are there other issues or things to consider when writing a large software project using a functional language?

Thanks!

Comment: My curiosity -- Does anyone know of an large open source program implemented in a functional language?  (Should I post this as a separate question?)

Comment: @Frank: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468205/functional-languages-real-life-examples

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Does program flow become difficult to follow more quickly than if a >non-functional language is used?

"Program flow" is probably the wrong concept to analyze a large functional program.  Control flow can become baroque because there are higher-order functions, but these are generally easy to understand because there is rarely any shared mutable state to worry about, so you can just think about arguments and results.  Certainly my experience is that I find it much easier to follow an aggressively functional program than an aggressively object-oriented program where parts of the implementation are smeared out over many classes.  And I find it easier to follow a program written with higher-order functions than with dynamic dispatch.  I also observe that my students, who are more representative of programmers as a whole, have difficulties with both inheritance and dynamic dispatch.  They do not have comparable difficulties with higher-order functions.

> Are there other issues or things to consider when writing a large 
>   software project using a functional language?

The critical thing is a good module system.  Here is some commentary.

- The most powerful module system I know of the [unit system of PLT Scheme](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.14.4663&rep=rep1&type=pdf) designed by Matthew Flatt and Matthias Felleisen.  This very powerful system unfortunately lacks static types, which I find a great aid to programming.
- The next most powerful system is the Standard ML module system.  Unfortunately Standard ML, while very expressive, also permits a great many questionable constructs, so it is easy for an amateur to make a real mess.  Also, many programmers find it difficult to use Standard ML modules effectively.

  The Objective Caml module system is very similar, but there are some differences which tend to mitigate the worst excesses of Standard ML.  The languages are actually very similar, but the styles and idioms of Objective Caml make it significantly less likely that beginners will write insane programs.
- The least powerful/expressive module system for a functional langauge is the Haskell module system.  This system has a grave defect that there are **no explicit interfaces**, so most of the cognitive benefit of having modules is lost.  Another sad outcome is that while the Haskell module system gives users a hierarchical name space, use of this name space (`import qualified`, in case you're an insider) is often deprecated, and many Haskell programmers write code as if everything were in one big, flat namespace.  This practice amounts to abandoning another of the big benefits of modules.

If I had to write a big system in a functional language and had to be sure that other people understood it, I'd probably pick Standard ML, and I'd establish very stringent programming conventions for use of the module system.  (E.g., explicit signatures everywhere, opague ascription with `:>`, and no use of `open` anywhere, ever.)  For me the simplicity of the Standard ML core language (as compared with OCaml) and the more functional nature of the Standard ML Basis Library (as compared with OCaml) are more valuable than the superior aspects of the OCaml module system.

I've worked on just one really big Haskell program, and while I found (and continue to find) working in Haskell very enjoyable, I really missed not having explicit signatures.

> Do functional languages cope well with complexity?

Some do.  I've found ML modules and module types (both the Standard ML and Objective Caml) flavors invaluable tools for managing complexity, understanding complexity, and placing unbreachable firewalls between different parts of large programs.  I have had less good experiences with Haskell

---

Final note: these aren't really new issues.  Decomposing systems into modules with separate interfaces checked by the compiler has been an issue in Ada, [C](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/software/cii/), C++, CLU, Modula-3, and I'm sure many other languages.  The main benefit of a system like Standard ML or Caml is the that you get explicit signatures and modular type checking (something that the C++ community is currently struggling with around templates and concepts).  I suspect that these issues are timeless and are going to be important for any large system, no matter the language of implementation.

Comment: How big is a "really big Haskell program"?

Answer (score 14):

Functional programming aims to *reduce* the complexity of large systems, by isolating each operation from others. When you program without side-effects, you know that you can look at each function individually - yes, understanding that one function may well involve understanding other functions too, but at least you know it won't interfere with some other piece of system state elsewhere.

Of course this is assuming completely pure functional programming - which certainly isn't always the case. You can use more traditional languages in a functional way too, avoiding side-effects where possible. But the principle is an important one: avoiding side-effects leads to more maintainable, understandable and testable code.

Comment: I'd call it a dream rather than a principle. Purely functional programming inevitably means non-strict (lazy) evaluation. That defers work that costs time and space (memory) in unpredictable ways. Although there is no mathematical dependence between separate functions their time and space requirements can still be interdependent. One order of evaluation can run out of memory or take too long when another would not have done. This reduction in maintainability, comprehensibility and testability is a serious problem for purely functional programming.

Answer (score 5):

I'd say the opposite. It is easier to reason about programs written in functional languages due to the lack of side-effects.

Comment: Well usually most functional languages do have *some* side-effects so that they can input data and output their results, for example. I'd say that functional languages *encourage* you to write code without side-effects rather than prohibit it. Thanks for the comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is not a matter of "functional" vs "procedural"; it is rather a matter of lazy evaluation.

Lazy evaluation is when you can handle values without actually computing them yet; rather, the value is attached to an expression which should yield the value if it is needed. The main example of a language with lazy evaluation is Haskell. Lazy evaluation allows the definition and processing of conceptually infinite data structures, so this is quite cool, but it also makes it somewhat more difficult for a human programmer to closely follow, in his mind, the sequence of things which will really happen on his computer.

For mostly historical reasons, most languages with lazy evaluation are "functional". I mean that these language have good syntaxic support for constructions which are typically functional.

Without lazy evaluation, functional and procedural languages allow the expression of the same algorithms, with the same complexity and similar "readability". Functional languages tend to value "pure functions", i.e. functions which have no side-effect. Order of evaluation for pure function is irrelevant: in that sense, pure functions help the programmer in knowing what happens by simply flagging parts for which knowing what happens in what order is not important. But that is an indirect benefit and pure functions also appear in procedural languages.

Comment: I don't think this is the question at all. It's an interesting question in its own right, but it's not this question.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can say, here are the key advantages of functional languages to cope with complexity :

1. Functional programming hates side-effects. 
   You can really black-box the different layers 
   and you won't be afraid of parallel processing 
   ([actor model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model) like in Erlang is really  easier to use 
   than locks and threads).
2. Culturally, functional programmer
   are used to design a DSL to express
   and solve a problem. Identifying the fundamental 
   primitives of a problem is a radically 
   different approach than rushing to the brand
   new trendy framework.
3. Historically, this field has been led by very smart people : 
   garbage collection, object oriented, metaprogramming... 
   All those concepts were first implemented on functional platform. 
   There is plenty of literature.

But the downside of those languages is that they lack support and experience in the industry. Having portability, performance and interoperability may be a real challenge where on other platform like Java, all of this seems obvious. That said, a language based on the JVM like Scala could be a really nice fit to benefit from both sides.

Comment: I have to disagree with this slightly.  Functional programming languages haven't gained much traction in industry, but the features of those languages have been adopted whole-heartedly.  Lambdas, garbage collection and the STL are all based on foundations laid by functional programming.

Comment: And generics are parametric polymorphism from ML (1973).

Answer (score 0):

> Does program flow become difficult to
>   follow more quickly than if a
>   non-functional language is used?

This may be the case, in that functional style encourages the programmer to prefer thinking in terms of abstract, logical transformations, mapping inputs to outputs. Thinking in terms of "program flow" presumes a sequential, stateful mode of operation--and while a functional program may have sequential state "under the hood", it usually isn't structured around that.

The difference in perspective can be easily seen by comparing imperative vs. functional approaches to "process a collection of data". The former tends to use structured iteration, like a `for` or `while` loop, telling the program "do this sequence of tasks, then move to the next one and repeat, until done". The latter tends to use abstracted recursion, like a `fold` or `map` function, telling the program "here's a function to combine/transform elements--now use it". It isn't necessary to follow the recursive program flow through a function like `map`; because it's a stateless abstraction, it's sufficient to think in terms of what it means, not what it's doing.

It's perhaps somewhat telling that the functional approach has been slowly creeping into non-functional languages--consider `foreach` loops, Python's list comprehensions...