# Functional techniques in the "real world"

Tags: functional-programming

As an avid functional programmer I am always interested in getting more people into the spirit of functional programming. So usually I try to explain the benefits FP would offer them to others, but alas no good luck so far. One argument that often comes up in this discussions is that FP sounds really nice, but actually seems only to be suited to limited academic purposes. This is usually backed up by the argument, that hardly any company does use functional language.

I cannot give any substantial arguments against the lack of uses of FP in companies beside the inherent chicken-egg problem in that argument (I only know two companies using OCaml, and I don't think the situation is any better for other languages).

However one way out of this argument is often to show them where techniques from FP (although maybe not the languages) have made it to the mainstream and are maybe already benefitting them right now. For example since I use a lot of C++ as well, I often cite the STL-Algorithm package, which is completely done in a functional way, since OOP is just not up to the task of easily separating data structures and algorithms on them. Another example would be git, which uses an immutable data structure very similar to the way trees are represented in any FP language (actually besides the backlink to previous revisions it is exactely the same), because this datastructure offers the simplest and fastest persistency.

What other examples uses of FP-techniques in the wild can you give?

Comment: C# 3.5 and above is moving programmers to FP.  It supports lambda expression and LINQ extensions for IEnumerable are just wonderful. See http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/rmcochran/introduction-to-functional-programming-in-C-Sharp/.

Comment: Just from curiosity. You said you know 2 companies using OCaml, which companies? (I just know Jane Street)

Comment: Jane street is one of them, the other is MLState (but they still are a small startup).

Comment: Also, duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468205/functional-languages-real-life-examples

Comment: I think this question is of 2nd rank importance. The way I'd go here was to convinve them that certain FP idioms are indeed better (in more than 1 sense). And then, you can argument along the line: You decline to do something *despite* the fact that you *know* it's better? How insane is this?

Comment: @Marcin: Actually this is not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468205/functional-languages-real-life-examples , however the differences are very slim. I am mostly interested in examples, where techniques and idioms from functional languages are used, not where functional languages are used. See for example the git case. Git is neither a functional language, nor is it written in a language anywhere close to a functional language (it's written in C). However it uses functional datastructures and gains its power from them.

Comment: "I only know two companies using OCaml, and I don't think the situation is any better for other languages". We have 1,000 corporate clients who have paid us for OCaml or F# related products or services including Apple, Sun, Intrech, DV Studio, Hubbard One, Everita, Acacia, Gambit, Canon, Bedi, LMS, Softship, Transmedia, Philips, Plankton, Nokia, Open Fuel, Dual Tech...

Comment: @LiKao I believe Citrix have the second largest team of OCaml developers in the world.

Comment: Halo 3 and Microsoft Bing are also partly written in F#.

Answer (score 3):

One example I think is High Frequency Trading. I do think that are a number of companies out there that use Erlang. E.g. [Sergey Aleyniko](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sergey_Aleynikov) had according to my memory been accused to have taken Erlang code that was part of the Goldman and Sachs HF trading platform with him. In fact Jane Street is also into trading.

For Erlang I further believe that Ericsson is using it themselves. Also I think it is frequently used in the Telco area for messaging services. Just do a Google search for i.e. Erlang Jobs. A number of FP related jobs from a lot of different companies comes back.

Comment: Trayport's Joule front-end for European energy traders is written in F#. http://www.slideshare.net/ptrelford/functional-architecture-goto-copenhagen-2012